# How Do I Create A Transition Diagram Of Finite Automata In Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

i am developing a Project i.e GUI model to convert Regular Expression into Finite Automata, as for the GUI Display i want to show the Diagram of Finite Automata,
in Visual Studio.
Please give me suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

[Microsoft Research Automata Tool Kit](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/39c51620-548c-49a3-ac9c-40d807010c07/)